# Can't install custom rom: "Can't mount SD card"

Tags: htc-desire, external-sd, mount, nandroid

I've some trouble with my HTC Desire and I'd like to ask for help.
I've recently rooted it with unrevoked and turned in S-off mode. All went well, or so it seemed, until I decided to flash a custom rom. I get problem either while doing nandroid backup and backup using rom manager (free version). Both cases give the following error:

- can't mount sd card

I'm pretty sure my sd card is working well cause I'm using link2sd and it works well. The sd card has 2 partitions done with g-parted: Ext3 and FAT32.
Moreover I have trouble downloading a custom rom via rom manager, it gives a download error.

Comment: What order are the partitions in (as in, which is first in the partition list)?

Comment: the first is ext3, the smallest one used as 'second rom'

Comment: You may want to try putting the FAT32 partition first and the ext3 second, if possible. Android might only be looking at the first partition on the SD card.

Comment: Finally I did it, the problem was the partitions' order. Thank you @eldarerathis !!!

Comment: @eldarerathis Your comment hould become a answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, one thing to be aware of is that (typically) the order of the partitions matters. Android basically only looks at the first partition in the table, so you need to make sure the FAT one is first on the disk and the ext2/3/4 one is second. Otherwise Android will see the ext partition and won't know what to do with it.